# Отобразить связанные объекты в шаблоне

Tags: django-orm, python, шаблоны, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вывожу в Django-шаблоне таблицу для показа Пользователю его заказов, но не могу понять, а как отобразить в заказах список купленных товаров. При проходе циклом для всех заказов показывается последняя запись, а ведь каждому заказу соответствуют разные товары.

Шаблон:

```
{%if orders%}
            {% for order in orders%}
            <tr>
                    <td>{{order.order_date}}</td>
                    <td>№{{order.order_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.address.address_state}},{{order.address.address_city}},{{order.address.address_street}}</br>
                    д.{{order.address.address_house}}, кв.{{order.address.address_apartment}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            {% for item in items%}#Вот тут затык
                            <li>{{item}}</li>
                            {%endfor%}
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{order.order_price}}руб.</td>
                    <td>Не оплачен</td>
            </tr>
```

Views:

```
def show_order(request, user_id):
    args = {}
    user = auth.get_user(request)
    order = Order.objects.filter(order_user_id=user.id)
    #items = order.item_set.all()
    args['username'] = user.username
    args['orders'] = order

    #return render_to_response('account.html', {'orders': order, 'items':items ,'username': user.username})#Тут затык
    return render_to_response('account.html', args)
```

Comment: Покажите свой шаблон вывода и что поступает на вход в view.

Comment: Как вы устанавливаете список купленных товаров для заказа? То есть какой код добавляет товары в заказ при покупке (или выборе) пользователем?

Comment: словарь, только берет из цикла последнюю запись и вставляет ее всем заказам.
В данном примере уже все товары сформированы и добавлены в БД, мне нужен только вывод. Все таблицы связаны по ForeignKey.

Comment: Покажите, как связано в модели (лучше модель заказа всю) и какой код добавляет товар для конкретного заказа (как связка идёт?).

Comment: По-моему, я достаточно подробно описал проблему. В БД есть таблица Пользователь к нему по ForeignKey подключен Заказ (Order) , а к Order по ForeignKey подключены продукты (Item) вопрос как отобразить Item?

Answer (score 1):

Все решилось тегом {% with %}

```
{% with order.item_set.all|first as items %}
```

Comment: разве так не будет много запросов в базу?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, я ошибся, потому что неправильно представил вашу модель.

Вам нужно получить все items примерно так:

```
Item.objects.filter(order__id=int_order_id)
```

где `int_order_id` - запрашиваемый идентификатор заказа.

Например, так я получаю все комментарии для поста на сайте:

```
'comments_list': Comment.objects.filter(post__id=int_post_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы передавать `items` в шаблон, используйте в шаблоне `{%for item in order.item_set.all %}`. Минус такого подхода - на каждый заказ будет +1 запрос в базу.

Если это нежелательно - передавайте в шаблон все *items*, а уже в шаблоне делайте `{% regroup %}` по полю `order` (обратите внимание, items должны быть отсортированы по order, иначе это не сработает) и выводите получившиеся группы.

Comment: Оба варианта не сработали, к сожалению(